# SQL Coordinates Distance

Tags: java, sql, h2

Table: `UserCoordinate`, PK: `UserName`, Values: `X`, `Y`

Assuming `UserName` John is at the Coordinates (50,50)...

How to select the `UserCoordinate` rows that are within the distance of 20 that are closest to (50,50) with a limit of 30 results?

```
SELECT * FROM UserCoordinate
WHERE(
        SQRT(SQUARE(ABS(50 - X)) + SQUARE(ABS(50 - Y))) < 20
)
ORDER BY (SQRT(SQUARE(ABS(50 - X)) + SQUARE(ABS(50 - Y)))) ASC
LIMIT 30;
```

How to write the above correctly?

I'm using H2 database, and have full control over the program code (Java).

Comment: So what what exactly is the problem?

Comment: what's the problem ... errors? .. worng result? ... no result? .. show a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Comment: Sorry. Other than not being sure if this works, I'm quite concerned about the performance of the above query if there are a lot of `UserCoordinates`. It seems to me that using a huge Map where the coordinates are pre-mapped would be a lot faster, since it does not have to calculate all the rows twice to get the results.